# Filling the missing Days from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Can you please help me in sql , I have table from where I'am getting day wise data.
Let's say:

```
Select * from #tempTable
```

Result:-

```
Day      Amount
-----------------   
Saturday 16128.00
Monday  527008.00
Tuesday 407608.00
```

Above query you can see result 'SUNDAY' is missing so how to fill this missing days .

Comment: Create a help table (or view, or cte) returning all 7 days. OUTER JOIN.

Comment: How come you don't want Wednesday etc?

Comment: It's not only Sunday, but Wednesday, Thursday and Friday is missing as well. What about those?

Comment: there can be anyday missing , this time Sunday is missing , next time Saturday can be missing so missing day i want to fill .

Comment: Aha, so it's Sunday because the days range from Saturday to Tuesday, but ts missing out on Sunday in that range?

Comment: I just want to fill missing day in a week .

Comment: Qirel , Yes sir

Comment: How do you know that it isn't Wednesday, Thursday and Friday that isn't missing values, instead of Sunday?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT  DayNames, [Amount]
FROM
(
SELECT 'Saturday' AS [Day], 16128.00  AS [Amount] UNION ALL
SELECT 'Monday'  ,527008.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tuesday' ,407608.00
)DT
RIGHT JOIN 
(
SELECT DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(Dw,number,GETDATE())) As DayNames
FROM
    (
        SELECT number 
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values
        WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND 7 AND type = 'P'
        )dt2
    )Final
ON Final.DayNames = [Day]
```

Result

```
DayNames    Amount
-----------------------
Friday      NULL
Saturday    16128.00
Sunday      NULL
Monday      527008.00
Tuesday     407608.00
Wednesday   NULL
Thursday    NULL
```

We can use CHOOSE() In Sql to obtain the same result

```
SELECT  DayNames, [Amount]
FROM
(
SELECT 'Saturday' AS [Day], 16128.00  AS [Amount] UNION ALL
SELECT 'Monday'  ,527008.00 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tuesday' ,407608.00
)DT
RIGHT JOIN 
(
SELECT  DayNames
FROM
    (
        SELECT  CHOOSE(number  ,'Monday'
                               ,'Tuesday'
                               ,'Wednesday'
                               ,'Thursday'
                               ,'Friday'
                               ,'Saturday'
                               ,'Sunday') As DayNames
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values
        WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND 7 AND type = 'P'
        )dt2
    )Final
ON Final.DayNames = [Day]
```

Result

---

```
DayNames    Amount
---------------------
Monday      527008.00
Tuesday     407608.00
Wednesday   NULL
Thursday    NULL
Friday      NULL
Saturday    16128.00
Sunday      NULL
```